# P3 being subspace of vector space?

Tags: vector-spaces

V = P3 (all real polynomials of degree at most 3)

and
$S = \{p(x)\in P_3 | x·p'(x) = p(x),\} $

is it a subspace of vector space $V$?

Solution:
I don't even know is it possible for the equation x·p'(x) = p(x) to have any solutions.

I know the following rules, but how to apply the second?

1. Non-empty - true
2. For coefficients of the polynom, as following $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$, $(a,b,c,d)\in S$ and $(m,n,p,q) \in S$, but then, how to substitute to prove?
3. For $\alpha\in R$ and $(a,b,c,d) \in S$ multiplying $(a,b,c,d)$ by $\alpha$ leads to both sides having coefficient $\alpha$, so it's true

Comment: S consists of polynomials of the form: $p(x)=Cx$. (Solutions of the linear and separable differential equation $xp'(x)=p(x)$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the other answer is definitely correct, you could also check the claim directly. For instance, assume that $p, q \in S$ and let us show that $p+q \in S$. Calculating, we find that
$$x \cdot (p+q)'(x) = x \cdot (p'(x)+q'(x)) = x \cdot p'(x) + x\cdot q'(x) = p(x) + q(x) = (p+q)(x).$$